# How to keep language bar / keyboard layout select always active?

Tags: windows-10, user-interface, notification-area, user-experience

Maybe this is a XY problem, let me start with the real issue:

When I do some stuff on my Windows machine, I often tend to use the tray icons (click them). Sometimes they jump around.

I want to stop the icons from jumping to the left when I click the tray area.

I have identified the cause of jumping around to be the keyboard layout / language selector tool.

Here you can see it's not present (when I use snip tool or RDP):

[image]

But when I click on the tray area, the keyboard layout changer appears:

[image]

[image]

this gets me *every time*. I just want to change my sound volume. When I need to click other icons, the "jump" causes me to move icons around, which is annoying because that works against my muscle reflexes.

Is there any solution to either:

- Not let the tray icons jump around?
- Keep the keyboard layout option always enabled?

P.S. I have another work machine that I access via RDP, the keyboard layout changer is always enabled there - which means this is possible to fix?

Comment: I think you nicely saved yourself from any XY problem by actually identifying what it is you need to fix.

Comment: Check in *Settings > Personalization > Turn system icons on or off* if the "Input Indicator" is set to On.

Comment: @harrymc It's "on", as it is on my work provided laptop where the input indicator never goes away. I tried the following things: Uninstalling t-clock redux on my own machine; compare  settings in "Settings -> Personalization -> Taskbar" between PC's (own and work-provided). Also "Home -> Typing -> Advanced Keyboard Settings" (+ Including "Language Bar Options". And except for "Use small taskbar icons", all the settings are the same. I tried enabling use small taskbar icons on my work-provided pc, but the input indicator does not dissapear when using snip tool, like it does on my private pc.